# QCD condensate and lepton mass

Tags: mass, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quantum-anomalies, leptons

I read that the QCD U(1) anomaly is caused by the QCD condensate giving rise to quark masses. Does the QCD condensate also give masses to leptons (electron, mu, tau, neutrinos), or are these masses somehow connected to the QED U(1) anomaly, or are they just provided by the Higgs condensate?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214873/2451